# How to use footnotes inside `song` environment provided by the "songs" package?

Tags: xetex, environments, footnotes, songs

I am making a songbook containing songs which use archaic words, and would like to mark these words with footnotes including a description of the words, and have them printed on the bottom of the same page as the footnotemark appears. As the MWE illustrates, this is not possible straight away.

I have tried the following so far:

- Regular `\footnote{}` between `\beginsong` and `\endsong`: The footnotemark appears correctly, but the footnote text is nowhere to be seen.
- `\footnotemark` mark between `\beginsong` and `\endsong` and

  - `\footnotetext{Test1}` just before `\endsong`: Footnote text nowhere to be found.
  - `\footnotetext{Test2}` just before `\end{song}`: Footnote text "Test2" is printed on a page before the song text with footnote number "2".
  - `\footnotetext{Test3}` outside the `songs` environment entirely: Footnote text "Test3" is printed on a page after the song text with footnote number "2".

Hence the page on which the footnote marks are present, is allergic to footnote text!

Does anybody have a solution to this problem?

Note: I use `XeLaTeX`. The same is produced if I compile with `pdfLaTeX`.

### MWE

```
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper,norsk,twoside
%,twocolumn
]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[lyric]{songs}
\usepackage{libertinus-otf}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[variant=bokmal]{norwegian}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}
    \begin{songs}{}
    \beginsong{Underfullt det er å leve}[%
    by={Werner Skibsted},
    ]
    \beginverse
    Underfullt det er å leve
    Kjærlighetens liv i Gud,
    Så jeg slipper helt å streve
    Med å holde lovens bud
    \endverse
    
    \beginchorus
    Dypt i nådeflodens\footnote{flod=elv.} strømmer,
    Kilden ifra Golgata,
    Hvor ei synden meg fordømmer,
    Hviler jeg så trygg og glad.
    \endchorus
    
    \beginverse
    Det som ingen andre maktet,
    Har vår Gud i Sønnen gjort.
    Lammet\footnotemark som for oss ble slaktet,
    Åpnet for oss nådens port.
    \endverse
    \footnotetext{Test1}
    \endsong
    \footnotetext{Test2}
    \end{songs}
\footnotetext{Test3.}
\end{document}
```

### XeLaTeX output

[image][image][image]